# Spring 3 and JSR-330 annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

By reading this article, [Spring 3 and JSR-330 @Inject and @Named example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-and-jsr-330-inject-and-named-example/), the standard annotation from JSR-330 is recommended to used since Spring 3. Therefore, @Named should be used instead of @Component, @Repository and @Service. But how about @Controller in Spring MVC? I am aware of that the @Controller is also an @Component, and I had the same result in my test when using @Named. But I want to make sure if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can use a package scan to wire in controllers separately to other components.

For example, might use this in a webmvc-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

So just need to check if any thing like this exists in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But my question is, because of JSR-330, we should use `@Named public class MyDao`, not `@Repository public class MyDao`. I am wondering whether or not we should also apply the same rule to controller class.